# Reraise Exception with additional try-except block

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to do some cleanup on error and then re-raise the exception that caused the error:

```
try:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        raise ValueError('something happened')              # do something that could fail
except Exception as e:                                      # Clean up in case of any error
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except Exception as f:                                    # Cleaning up could fail too, but we are not interested in that one
        pass
    raise                                                   # This re-raises `e` if file deletion was OK
                                                            # but re-raises `f` if file deletion was not OK
```

The last `raise` statement may either raise `e` or `f`, depending on what happened. It is obviously not possible to replace

```
raise
```

with

```
raise e
```

as the original traceback would be destroyed. For me, the inner exception is more important than the outer one, so is there a way to raise that exception specifically?

Comment: Actually, I think the whole block can be reorganised to a `try..except..finally` block.

Comment: What's the issue? if you get an `OSError` you get a nested exception - `During handling of the above exception (ValueError), another exception occurred: (OSError)`

Comment: No, `try..except..finally` doesn't work here. @AChampion I want to reraise the inner exception, no matter if the outer one was thrown or not.

Comment: Why doesn't `finally` work? Your current approach only throws the inner if the outer has already been raised.

Comment: If I put `os.remove()` into the `finally` block it would always remove the file, even if there was no Exception thrown. And putting `raise` in `final` would still raise `e` or `f`.

Comment: Then I'm confused by 'I want to reraise the inner exception, no matter if the outer one was thrown or not.' Just replace `pass` with `raise` and then you will get the inner exception if it is thrown.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I confused *inner* and *outer*. I want `ValueError('something happened') ` to be reraised.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is with the nest exception:

```
try:
    raise ValueError('something happened')
except Exception as e:
    try:
        if random.randint(0,1):
            raise OSError('something else happened')
    except OSError:
        raise
    raise
```

For example:

```
import random
try:
    try:
        raise ValueError('something happened')
    except Exception:
        try:
            if random.randint(0,1):
                raise OSError('something else happened')
        except OSError:
            raise
        raise
except OSError:
    print('Hello')
except ValueError:
    print('Goodbye')
```

Randomly prints `Hello` or `Goodbye`.